# AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'preprocess' in tensorflow_federated tff

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I'm testing this tutorial with non-IID distribution for federated learning:
https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/tff_for_federated_learning_research_compression

In this posted question [TensorFlow Federated: How to tune non-IIDness in federated dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970504/tensorflow-federated-how-to-tune-non-iidness-in-federated-dataset) it suggested to use tff.simulation.datasets.build_single_label_dataset() as a way to produce a non-IID distribution for the dataset.

I tried to apply that first (see the code) and got an error !

```
emnist_train, emnist_test = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data(
    only_digits=False)
emnist_train1 = tff.simulation.datasets.build_single_label_dataset(
  emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients(),
  label_key='label', desired_label=1)

print(emnist_train1.element_spec)
```

> > OrderedDict([('label', TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('pixels', TensorSpec(shape=(28, 28), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))])

```
print(next(iter(emnist_train1))['label'])
```

> > tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)

```
MAX_CLIENT_DATASET_SIZE = 418

CLIENT_EPOCHS_PER_ROUND = 1
CLIENT_BATCH_SIZE = 20
TEST_BATCH_SIZE = 500

def reshape_emnist_element(element):
  return (tf.expand_dims(element['pixels'], axis=-1), element['label'])

def preprocess_train_dataset(dataset):
  return (dataset
          .shuffle(buffer_size=MAX_CLIENT_DATASET_SIZE)
          .repeat(CLIENT_EPOCHS_PER_ROUND)
          .batch(CLIENT_BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=False)
          .map(reshape_emnist_element))

emnist_train1 = emnist_train1.preprocess(preprocess_train_dataset)

>> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cda96c33a0f6> in <module>()
     15           .map(reshape_emnist_element))
     16 
---> 17 emnist_train1 = emnist_train1.preprocess(preprocess_train_dataset)

AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'preprocess'
```

Since dataset is filtered, it is not able to preprocess!
So, in this case, it is filtered based on what label?

```
... label_key='label', desired_label=1)
```

**the desired label = 1 for which label in EMNIST?**

**My Question is:**

How can I apply this function tff.simulation.datasets.build_single_label_dataset()
to get non-IID dataset ***(different number of samples for each client)*** in this specific tutorial ! https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/tff_for_federated_learning_research_compression in details without error regarding the filtered dataset!

Appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there is some confusion between the [`tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData) and [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) APIs that would be useful to cover.

`tf.data.Dataset` does *not* have a `preprocess` method, with [`tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.preprocess`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData#preprocess) does exist.

However, [`tff.simulation.datasets.build_single_label_dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/build_single_label_dataset) uses `tf.data.Dataset` instances: both the input argument and the output result as `tf.data.Dataset` instances. In this case, `emnist_train1` is a `tf.data.Dataset` which does *not* have a `preprocess` method.

However, all is not lost! The `preprocess_train_dataset` function takes a `tf.data.Dataset` argument, and returns a `tf.data.Dataset` result. This should mean that replacing:

```py
emnist_train1 = emnist_train1.preprocess(preprocess_train_dataset)
```

with

```py
emnist_train1 = preprocess_train_dataset(emnist_train1)
```

will create a `tf.data.Dataset` with only a single label ("label non-IID") that is shuffled, repeated, batched, and reshaped. Note that a single `tf.data.Dataset` is generally used to represent *one* user in the federated algorithm. To create more, with a random number of batches, something like the following could work:

```py
client_datasets = [
   emnist_train1.take(random.randint(1, MAX_BATCHES))
   for _ in range(NUM_CLIENTS)
]
```

Comment: Thanks Zachary for your correct and complete answer

Comment: I got an error regarding MapDataset again later in the code! can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72146421/attributeerror-mapdataset-object-has-no-attribute-client-ids-in-tensorflow